# Assured Delivery (Messaging) datapower XI52 / WMB

Tags: messaging

Both products Datapower XI52 and Websphere message broker support messaging.

Assured Delivery (Messaging) - is it true that only WMB can support and datapower XI52 cannot support.

Can we use Datapower XI52 for reliable messaging - can handle failovers and reprocess failed transactions.

Appreciate any advise.

Thank you

Comment: I don't agree with this. My question is very specific. Does Datapower XI52 assure guaranteed delivery when used for messaging ? YES or NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve assured delivery it is needed that the message transport layer and the transport protocol provided by it work together with your ESB, regardless of the ESB you use.
For example using WebSphere MQ to transport the messages, both the Message Broker and the DataPower XI52 can be configured to guaranty assured delivery even in case of the failure of the ESB or MQ.

This may give you the basic idea for the XI52 (check out the part about units of work):
http://guide2.webspheremq.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/DataPower-for-MQ-Guide-Share-MQ-Interoperability.pdf

Comment: i agree. By using Websphere MQ - yes.

Comment: My question is different though. If we are not using WMB or Websphere MQ and using only Data power XI52 ; Can Datapower assure guaranteed delivery of messages to process failed messages (e.g. multi protocol gateway datapower capability used, http requested submitted and queue delivered to XYZ destination).

Comment: Found the answer. Looks like the answer is NO. Thanks everyone.